# How do you add Bootstrap Themes to REACT App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import About from "./About";
import Shop from "./Shop";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
           <Nav />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
              <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
         </Router>
       );
     }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If by add "boostrap themes" you mean all the bootstrap CSS and styling, you can import it from the minified bootstrap package.

See [getting started](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets)

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of
> Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some
> stylesheet is required to use these components.
>
> CSS
>
> ```
> {/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/}
>
> import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
> ```

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import About from "./About";
import Shop from "./Shop";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```